# SQL: How to create a database view from tables with OneToMany Relationship?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, one-to-many, database-view

There are three available tables and columns:

```
Core - EmpID, EmpName
       1, Yagga Boshu

External - ExternalEmpID, ExternalDeptName
           1 , Capegemini

Position - EmpID, Dept  P/S
           1, IT        Primary
           1, Finance   Secondary
```

I want to create view from in following format:

```
   Emp ID, EmpName, ExternalID, ExternalName, EmpPrimaryDept, EmpSecondaryDept
   1,     Yagga Boshu,  1 ,      CapeGemini  ,  IT,           FINANCE
```

1. EmpID and EmpName comes from Core Table.
2. ExternalID and ExternalName comes from External Table which is OneToOne with core table
3. EmpPrimaryDept and EmpSecondaryDept comes from Position Table which
   is OneToMany with core table

For 1) and 2) following query works:

```
select * from CORE ec, EXTERNAL ee
where ec.EMPLOYEEID = ee.ExternalEmpID
```

How to join Position table so that return comes in one row as described above?

- There are 20,000 Employees data in core.
- In question where you see 1 Emp ID those are linkage between two tables.
- I am using Oracle Database
  12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: How one will decide that which is the primary department and which is the secondary department? Is there any flag or some logic to identify it?

Comment: For a start you can look for [pivot queries](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html) as that's more or less what you need here...

Comment: why empid 1 is having two depts in output but in position there are two seperate empids 1 and 2 or you din provide relevant data

Comment: I have the same questions. **(1)** What links EmpID 1 to ExternalEmpID 1? Neither does the Core table contain an ExternalEmpID nor does the External table contain an EmpID. **(2)** What links the Finance department to these employees? Finance seems to be linked to EmpID 2 and should have nothing to do with EmpID 1 hence.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I am sorry, It is employee 1.. All 1s are linked to each other. Updated query and data for understanding. 1 is working in IT and 1 is working with finance so position table has 2 entries against 1 core. If it works with some external then it can thave third entry too but for now take it as two.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: Sorry updated question. It is 1 which is linked to all two tables where both has 1

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980: Yes. I have updated question

Comment: @Radagast81: Yes, i have updated question. All values 1 are Foreign keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use subqueries in the `select` clause:

```
select
  c.empid, c.empname, e.externaldeptname,
  (select dept from position p where p.empid = c.empid and p.p_s = 'Primary') as dept1,
  (select dept from position p where p.empid = c.empid and p.p_s = 'Secondary') as dept2
from core c
left join external e on e.externalempid = c.empid
order by c.empid;
```

You can also move them to the `from` clause:

```
select
  c.empid, c.empname, e.externaldeptname, p.dept as dept1, s.dept as dept2
from core c
left join external e on e.externalempid = c.empid,
left join (select empid, dept from position where p_s = 'Primary') p on p.empid = c.empid
left join (select empid, dept from position where p_s = 'Secondary') s on s.empid = c.empid
order by c.empid;
```

Comment: Thanks, Both worked like charm but take a lot of time to fetch data. Any alternative you suggest? ( 50 rows in 700ms)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just need a `LISTAGG`after joining your 3 tables for secondary dept.

```
    select EmpID, ec.EmpName
   , ee.ExternalDeptName
       ee.Dept, 
         LISTAGG(p.dept,',') as 
        'PrimarySecondaryDepts.' from
        CORE ec join EXTERNAL ee 
       on ec.empid =ee.empid join 
       Position p
        ec.empid=p.empid group by empid, 
         ec.empname, 
       ee.ExternalDeptName,
       ee.Dept
```